# filter an array using ajax in php

Tags: php, ajax, jquery

I read similar questions here, but didn't find my answer. Actually i have an array of data which i am passing to my view file from my controller. There i am iterating through it to show data in the table like below:

AbcController(abcAction) :

```
$this->view->array = $array;
```

and it's corresponding view file : abc.phtml :

```
<?php foreach($this->array as $object){ ?> *** table to display data*** <?php }?>
```

I am able to sort through postback but i want to sort this data through ajax call. i had done sorting logic in my controller. Ajax call should return this sorted array which i will show in table as i am showing above in phtml file. What i had learned in ajax, i am not able to implement it. Can anyone help me out in this.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

json_decode and json_encode.  Is what I believe you are asking for.

Comment: I had tried with this, but not able to resolve it. Can you give me a simple example with above reference. Thanks for response.

Comment: It's none of that.  It would be $encoded_ary = json_encode($this->array);

Comment: ya i had done it like this. But i am not able to get the response. $.ajax({
  type : 'POST',
  url : 'Abccontoller/abcaction',
  data :  json_encode($this->array),
  success : function(data){
        }  
    });    data ddoesnot have anything.... it's null..